# Calling a block of another widget inside a widget loses all widget attributes

Tags: symfony, twig

In Symfony, you can define blocks to describe how a form type can look. For example, a `ChoiceType` (used for select, radio, checkboxes) can be redesigned by creating a block like this

```
{%- block choice_widget -%}
{%- endblock choice_widget -%}
```

Now when rendering a form field of this type an empty HTML string should come out.

Okay, let's go to my problem now. I have created a `FormType` which has the option `short` which is a boolean and should describe if I want a short configuration (only 1-2 settings) of the widget or all settings.

So, what I was doing was creating a new block for my widget

```
{%- block my_new_widget -%}
{%- endblock my_new_widget -%}
```

And inside I wanted to do this

```
{%- block my_new_widget -%}
    {% if short %}
        // Do my stuff here
    {% else %}
        {{ block('choice_widget') }}
    {% endif %}
{%- endblock my_new_widget -%}
```

So, for explanation: When short is false, I want simply the default `choice_widget` to be rendered.

And this is where the problem comes. In my `choice_widget` my first line looks like this

`{%- if required and placeholder is none -%}`

When I now render `my_new_widget` I'm getting an error that `required` is not defined.

This only happens when I tell twig to render the `choice_widget` block by myself. When I completely remove `my_new_widget` and let it just render the `choice_widget` it works without problems.

In both cases my `choice_widget` is def. called because when I add this to the choice_widget

`TEST {%- if required and placeholder is none -%}`

`TEST` gets output. So it seems to use the correct widget, however all widget attributes are lost when I include a block. Is this the desired behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it seems there is an Issue for this already on `GitHub`

https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/1302

And it seems like the way to go is

```
{% with {
    'collector': profile.getcollector(name),
    'profiler_url': profiler_url,
    'token': profile.token,
    'name': name
  } %}
    {{ block('toolbar', template) }}
{% endwith %}
```